# My button is not segueing

Tags: swift, button, segue

I have a button in a viewcontroller without a navigation bar (I don't really think this matters). When I click on the button I want to segue to another view controller but it is not working. I am programmatically segueing to the SecondViewcontroller using this:

```
   @IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatting", sender: self)
    }
```

[image]
I set up the show relationship in storyboard and set the identifier to "chatting". I am really confused because I used the exact same set up for another button in another view controller and that works. However, in this case, I get the error:
"fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"

This is what my entire FirstViewController looks like:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseAuth
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
import FirebaseDatabase

class UsersProfileViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource  {

    @IBOutlet var Usersname: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var UsersProfilePic: UIImageView!

    @IBOutlet var TableView: UITableView!

    var username: String?
    var userpicuid: String?
    var posts = NSMutableArray()
    var loggedInUser = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser




    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        TableView.delegate = self
        TableView.dataSource = self


        //Making the Facebook profile pic round
        self.UsersProfilePic.layer.borderWidth = 2.0
        self.UsersProfilePic.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        self.UsersProfilePic.layer.cornerRadius = self.UsersProfilePic.frame.size.width/2
        self.UsersProfilePic.clipsToBounds = true


        //set the user's pic and name
        self.Usersname.text = self.username


        if let postProfile = self.userpicuid{

                let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child((userpicuid)!+"/profile_pic.jpg")

                imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                    if error == nil {

                        let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                        self.UsersProfilePic.image = image




                    }else {

                        print("Error downloading image:" )

                    }})}


    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }

    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = false

    }

    // Properties of the UITableView


    func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        TableView.separatorStyle  = .none


            return self.posts.count


          }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "UsersCell", for: indexPath) as! UserProfileTableViewCell

        //Configure the cell


        print(posts[indexPath.row])
        let post = self.posts[indexPath.row] as! [String: AnyObject]
        cell.Title.text = post["title"] as? String
        cell.Author.text = post["Author"] as? String
        //  cell.ISBN.text = post["ISBN"] as? String
        cell.Price.text = post["Price"] as? String
        cell.CustomView.layer.cornerRadius = 7
        cell.CustomView.layer.masksToBounds = false
        cell.CustomView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.withAlphaComponent(0.2).cgColor
        cell.CustomView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0)
        cell.CustomView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.8

        if let imageName = post["image"] as? String {

            let imageRef = FIRStorage.storage().reference().child("images/\(imageName)")


            imageRef.data(withMaxSize: 25 * 1024 * 1024, completion: { (data, error) -> Void in
                if error == nil {

                    let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                    cell.Book.image = image


                }else {

                    print("Error downloading image:" )
                }})}

        return cell
        }

///THIS IS THE END OF THE TABLEVIEW PROPERTIES//////

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


    @IBAction func sendMessage(_ sender: Any) {
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "chatting", sender: self)
    }

    @IBAction func SwipeBack(_ sender: UISwipeGestureRecognizer) {

    }


}
```

This is my console log:

```
**2017-05-16 13:35:11.462713-0400 Lit_Swap[7837:4207118] WARNING: Firebase Analytics App Delegate Proxy is disabled. To log deep link campaigns manually, call the methods in FIRAnalytics+AppDelegate.h.
2017-05-16 13:35:11.467597-0400 Lit_Swap[7837:4207118] Firebase automatic screen reporting is enabled. Call +[FIRAnalytics setScreenName:setScreenClass:] to set the screen name or override the default screen class name. To disable automatic screen reporting, set the flag FirebaseAutomaticScreenReportingEnabled to NO in the Info.plist
2017-05-16 13:35:11.621902-0400 Lit_Swap[7837:4207181] [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
2017-05-16 13:35:11.622 Lit_Swap[7837] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000001] Configuring the default app.
2017-05-16 13:35:11.651567-0400 Lit_Swap[7837:4207186] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3600000 started
2017-05-16 13:35:11.652 Lit_Swap[7837:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics v.3600000 started
2017-05-16 13:35:11.654094-0400 Lit_Swap[7837:4207186] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2017-05-16 13:35:11.654 Lit_Swap[7837:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> To enable debug logging set the following application argument: -FIRAnalyticsDebugEnabled 
2017-05-16 13:35:11.810969-0400 Lit_Swap[7837:4207181] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
2017-05-16 13:35:11.811 Lit_Swap[7837:] <FIRAnalytics/INFO> Firebase Analytics enabled
2017-05-16 13:35:12.717443-0400 Lit_Swap[7837:4207118] Could not load the "User Filled-50" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.JesamUsani.Lit-Swap"
2017-05-16 13:35:12.717775-0400 Lit_Swap[7837:4207118] Could not load the "User Filled-50" image referenced from a nib in the bundle with identifier "com.JesamUsani.Lit-Swap"
2017-05-16 13:35:12.728010-0400 Lit_Swap[7837:4207118] Failed to set (clipToBounds) user defined inspected property on (UINavigationItem): [<UINavigationItem 0x1701de000> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key clipToBounds.
2017-05-16 13:35:12.872870-0400 Lit_Swap[7837:4207181] [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed.
2017-05-16 13:35:12.872 Lit_Swap[7837] <Debug> [Firebase/Core][I-COR000019] Clearcut post completed.2017-05-16 13:35:20.147426-0400 Lit_Swap[7837:4207182] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles
2017-05-16 13:35:20.148996-0400 Lit_Swap[7837:4207182] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings.
fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value
2017-05-16 13:35:22.856791-0400 Lit_Swap[7837:4207118] fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value**
```

[image]

Comment: provide error message please, what is actually nil?

Comment: Did you hook up the IBAction to the button

Comment: @DanielLegler yes the button is sendMessage

Comment: @JuicyFruit i'm not sure, I can't find it

Comment: @juelizabeth just copy and paste console log

Comment: Did you segue by right clicking the button and dragging to SecondViewController? Should be done from the first vc itself.

Comment: @JuicyFruit I have updated my question

Comment: @DanielLegler no my segue is not done by dragging from the button to the SecondViewController. It was done by dragging from the FirstViewController to the SecondViewController and then giving the identifier a name

Comment: Show your whole view controller code. Is it crashing only when you press the button?

Comment: @DanielLegler i have included my entire viewcontroller and yes it only crashes when i press the button

Comment: Try to replace `sender: self` with `sender: sender`.

Comment: @user6603599 it sadly still doesn't work

Comment: @juelizabeth or `sender: nil`

Comment: @user6603599 still getting the same error

Comment: Are you sure you have written the segue name correctly in storyboard?

Comment: @user6603599 yes, I copy and pasted it and if I didn't I would get a different error message

Comment: Can you right click on the button and see what outlets its connected to? Also, in your call stack, after the crash, you should be able to see at which line in your code is crashing.

Comment: When I right click on the button it is connected by Touch Up Inside to UsersProfile sendMessage: I have also included a screenshot of the error page. @TheAppMentor

Comment: @juelizabeth want to do small teamviewer session to fix that issue?

Comment: @Shabirjan yes please, how do you do that?

Comment: do you have teamviewer installed?

Comment: @Shabirjan yes, I just downloaded it

Comment: share the id and pass for that

Comment: It could be possible that you have not initialised something in the second VC. missed an outlet or something. Please check your second VC.